# I answered a Community Wiki question and I got up voted. Why didn't I get any reputation?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, community-wiki

I answered a Community Wiki question and I got up voted. Why didn't I get any reputation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Votes on community wiki posts won't affect anybody's reputation.

Comment: then vote don't have any benefit in wiki? just come up your answer?

Comment: @Am: That is what he said. Yes. Perhaps you should read the FAQ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq "Note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation." You'll still get badges.  Note that if you earned any rep from it *before* entering community wiki mode, you'll keep it.

Comment: CW posts are often used when there is no "Right" or "Wrong" answer, but when people might agree/disagree with a topic. Nobody wants to loose rep just because someone disagrees on a highly subjective topic, and nobody should gain rep because of the opposite

Answer (score 1):

This is from the FAQ:

> (Note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation.)

This is a previous question about what community wiki's are suppose to be:

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

They were intended to not build reputation. Here is the answer information from that question:

> ### Why have *Community Wiki* posts?
>
> One of the goals of Stackoverflow is
> to be a continually evolving source of
> good information.  Community Wiki
> posts help enhance the *wiki* aspect
> of the site.
>
> ### How do *Community Wiki* posts work?
>
> Community Wiki posts work by
> transferring ownership of the post
> from the original author to the
> community.  They make the post easier
> to edit and maintain by a wider group
> of users, but they do not contribute
> to any user's reputation.  Community
> Wiki posts are marked as *community
> wiki*.
>
> Some of the key features are:
>
> - Community Wiki posts are owned by the [Community User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1), not by any
>   individual user.
> - A much lower reputation is needed to edit a community wiki post.
> - Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's
>   reputation.
> - The original author still gets badges based on community posts.
> - The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before
>   their post entered community mode.
>
> ### How does a post become a *Community Wiki* post?
>
> There are several ways a question or
> answer can enter community wiki mode,
> and most of these ways will occur
> automatically based on the rules of
> the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when:
>
> - The body of the post has been edited by four different people.
> - The post has been edited six times by the original owner.
> - The post's author checks the *community wiki* checkbox when composing the question or answer.
> - The post is edited by its original author, who when doing so opts to
>   check the *community wiki*.
> - The question generates more than 30 answers.  In this case, the question
>   and all answers will enter community
>   mode, as will any future answers.
>
> ** note that the rules outlined
> above are based on observations; the
> actual behavior of SO is subject to
> change without notice, and may well
> have done so since this was last
> updated...*
>
> ### Miscellaneous
>
> - There is no way to reclaim your post back from community wiki mode.  This
>   is to prevent exploits and gaming of
>   the system.
> - Rollbacks do not reverse any of the community wiki mode calculations.